# Sending Firebase token to own server not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase

I'm trying to send token to mySQL database to be stored there. I'm calling the below method in myFirebaseMessagingService class in onNewToken() but nothing happens. The function is working but the token and username are not being stored in the database.

```
  private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            //Populate the request parameters
            request.put(KEY_USERNAME, "testUser");
            request.put(KEY_TOKEN, token);
            Log.d("test","request: " + request.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, submitToken_url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.v("test","This is php response");
                        try {
                            //Check if user got registered successfully
                            if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) == 0) {
                                //Set the user session
                               Log.v("test","Token Stored Successfully" + KEY_STATUS);

                            } else if (response.getInt(KEY_STATUS) != 0) {
                                Log.v("test","Token Storing Failed" + KEY_STATUS);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);
    }
```

This is also my php file:

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'db/db_connect.php'; 
//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array
//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['token']) ){
    $username = $input['username'];
    $token = $input['token'];
        //Query to register new user
        $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO firebaseUser(username,token) VALUES (?,?)";
        if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$token);
            $stmt->execute();
            $response["status"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "User Token Stored";
            $stmt->close();
        }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I added a log and got this error now `org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`

My Singleton class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
private static Context mCtx;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private MySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

}

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username,$token);` This should throw a error message, since you only have 2 parameters, you only need 2 datatype `"ss"`

Comment: Here the post that show you to enable error report in PHP for better debugging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @catcon thank. I don't know how i missed it. I changed it to "ss" but still no token being stored. is my java method correct? am i missing something else?

Comment: Can you post this  `MySingleton` class, please?

Comment: @JonathasNascimento Updated. Also, I use the similar method in the SignUp function and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I have updated my php file to the following:

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'db/db_connect.php';

//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['username']) && isset($input['token'])){
$username = $input['username'];
$token = $input['token'];


    //Query to register new user
    $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO firebaseUsers(username, token) VALUES (?,?)";
    if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$token);
        $stmt->execute();
        $response["status"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Token Saved";
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
else{
$response["status"] = 1;
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```